# Cucumber+Gherkin: Parse natural language to boolean

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumberjs

So, we just introduced Cucumber + Gherkin to explore e2e testing in our fairly fresh Angular2 project. We decided to write the step definitions in JS. I am trying to be fairly generic in the steps definitions.
This is what I am trying to achieve:

We have

`this.Then(/^I should see (.*) on the page$/, function(componentName, callback) {
    expect(element(by.id(componentName)).isPresent()).to.eventually.be.true;
    setTimeout(callback, 1000);
  });`

I would like to also allow definitions in the form of:

`Then I should not see Results on the page`

To denote that certain elements are not supposed to be displayed. Any elegant way of doing that or even built in-tools I could use? The documentation and googling only gave me things that included `true/false` in the description. I have a feeling that c'n'p will make our step definitions grow super quickly and make maintenance unnecessarily hard unless we figure out this kind of thing up front.
Stop me if you think this is a stupid idea and if so please tell me why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could catch the keyword 'not' in your step and implement two paths in your step implementation with a condition choosing the correct one.

I would, however, not do that and instead accept two steps. That would make your code easier to read and therefore less error prone.

I would work hard on making the steps one-liners and delegate the execution to a helper class. The helper class can have two ways in, the positive case and the negative case. It may also handle things like you seem to do with time out etc.

Re-writing your code, I would try to have something like this:

```
this.Then(/^I should see (.*) on the page$/, function(componentName) {
    isPresent(componentName);
  });
```

And the negative case as

```
this.Then(/^I should not see (.*) on the page$/, function(componentName) {
    isNotPresent(componentName);
  });
```

I'm not fluent in JavaScript so this may not be the Javascript way. But I would work hard on pushing potential common details to a helper and minimize the glue code needed between Gherkin and JavaScript.

Comment: That sounds like the reasonable middle-ground. Thanks!